# ion-item loses start padding when placed inside ion-item

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic7

I have multiple ion-input elements generated by `ngFor`.  I have fill set to `outline` to place a border around it, which applies padding.  When the div generating the elements is inside another div, all of the styling applies properly. However, once I place that div inside of an `ion-item` element, the padding at the start is overridden to 0, resulting in sharp corners and a generally unpleasant look.

```
<ion-item>
  <div id="filterList">
    <div *ngFor="let filter of filterConfigs">
      <div [ngSwitch]="filter.type">
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'dateRange'"
          ><ccd-pubfl-date-range-filter
            [column]="filter.column"
            (setFilter)="filterSettingsService.setRangeFilter($event)"
            (clearFilter)="filterSettingsService.removeFilter($event)"
          ></ccd-pubfl-date-range-filter
        ></ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'fileSizeRange'"
          ><ccd-pubfl-file-size-range-filter
            [column]="filter.column"
            (setFilter)="filterSettingsService.setRangeFilter($event)"
            (clearFilter)="filterSettingsService.removeFilter($event)"
          ></ccd-pubfl-file-size-range-filter
        ></ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'numberRange'"
          ><ccd-pubfl-number-range-filter
            [column]="filter.column"
            (setFilter)="filterSettingsService.setRangeFilter($event)"
            (clearFilter)="filterSettingsService.removeFilter($event)"
          ></ccd-pubfl-number-range-filter
        ></ng-container>
        <div *ngSwitchDefault>{{ filter.type }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-item>
```

Opening inspect element, it appears that the style overriding the padding and setting it to 0px is `ion-item.sc-ion-input-md-h:not(.item-label):not(.item-has-modern-input), ion-item:not(.item-label):not(.item-has-modern-input) .sc-ion-input-md-h`, but I have no idea what that actually means.  All of my inputs have the label property set, so it shouldn't be saying it isn't using the modern syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic components work in the shadow-dom so applying css like you did will not work. More info can be found in thier docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-shadow-parts

Comment: That's good to know!  Unfortunately it does not solve my problem, as the styling being overridden is the ionic styling, not styling I was attempting to apply via CSS.  When I set the `fill` property on the inputs to `outline`, it correctly puts a sort of bubble around it, like this
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#filled-inputs

However, once I put that input inside an `ion-item`, the bit of that bubble before the text gets hacked off, because it overrides the padding that telling it to outline automatically applied.  So the left side of the border is directly against the text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly your problem, since your description is different from the code you provided. But when you are trying to change CSS properties of Ionic elements, first have a look at the CSS Custom Properties in the doc page. [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item#css-custom-properties-1) is the ion-item's CSS Custom Properties, mentioning `--padding-start` and 7 other padding related css that you need to change when you want to manipulate the padding of ion-item.

Another note is that ion-item is not designed to be inside another ion-item. I don't know what is your usage, but ion-item are meant to hold ion-label, ion-icon and similar things in a nice application based row-like UI. I'd suggest placing the ion-inputs direction in ion-items, or if you want to use divs, don't use ion-items at all.